# django catching http-referer not working always

Tags: django

```
if 'HTTP_REFERER' in request.META and 'mysite.com' not in request.META['HTTP_REFERER'] or 'HTTP_REFERER' not in request.META:
    return redirect('/')
```

if `HTTP_REFERER` is there and if it doesnot contain `mysite.com` or if `HTTP_REFERER` not given, it should redirect to startpage.

my code is deployed over 7 servers, scheduled via loadbalancer, the code in all those 7 servers are uptodate. but still, only sometimes, this redirect is not working.

what may I be doing wrong?

the case, where it is not working:

one newssite published a news about my page and pasted a deep link from my page. and I clicked on that link, and it didnot redirect. I got surprised and checked my code, everything was ok, and clicked again on the link and bingo, this time it did redirect me to startpage. I was happy, I thought it may be a caching or smthg. but later, I clicked on the link and the redirect didnot work again. then posted this question. the case is independent of browser type and version.

Comment: Do you have examples of the cases where this is not working?

Comment: Is there any javascript click event on the link which could be affecting request? Also is this code being called on all views within your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this code could be shortened too:

```
if 'mysite.com' not in request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', ''):
    return redirect('/')
```

Secondly, `HTTP_REFERER` is not guaranteed to be present. It might just be users are using bookmarks, or browser autocomplete which will mean the HTTP_REFERER may or may not be present in the cases you are testing.

If a valid user of the site who uses a bookmark will be redirected. Likewise an invalid user who gets referred from `somedomain.com/mysite.com` will be redirected. In this case it might be better to use a `startwith()` when checking the referer. Is there not a better way you can manage what you are trying to do.

Maybe you can update the question with a little more context. I will be willing to help you as best as I can.

Comment: thank you for the warm help. I will update my question in a while with more context/use case